# Is there a preferred way collect a stream of lists into a flat list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was wondering, whether there is a preferred way to get from a stream of lists to a collection containing the elements of all the lists in the stream.
I can think of two ways to get there:

```
final Stream<List<Integer>> stream = Stream.empty();
final List<Integer> one = stream.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll);
final List<Integer> two = stream.flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The second option looks much nicer to me, but I guess the first one is more efficient in parallel streams.
Are there further arguments for or against one of the two methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference is that `flatMap` is an [*intermediate operation.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) while `collect` is a [*terminal operation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

So `flatMap` is *the only way* to process the flattened stream items if you want to do other operations than `collect`ing immediately.

Further `collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll)` is very hard to read given the fact that you have two identical method references `ArrayList::addAll` with completely different semantics.

Regarding parallel processing, your guess is wrong. The first one has lesser capabilities of parallel processing as it relies on `ArrayList.addAll` applied to the stream items (sub-lists) which can’t be broken into parallel sub-steps. In contrast, `Collectors.toList()` applied to a `flatMap` *can* do parallel processing of sub-list items if the particular `List`s encountered in the stream support it. But this will be relevant only if you have a rather small stream of rather big sub-lists.

The only drawback of `flatMap` is the intermediate stream creation which adds an overhead in the case that you have a lot of very small sub-lists.

But in your example, the stream is empty so it doesn’t matter (scnr).

Comment: Could you please elaborate, why the first version would not perform well in parallel stream? Intermediate operations in front of the collect could be performed in parallel and several ArrayLists could be maintained using the accumulator function (second parameter of collect). Afterwards the combiner (third parameter) would be used to collect all elements into one large ArrayList. (In this case, both functions would of course be the same, but used in a different way)

Comment: The parallelism is the same in both version regarding the **`Stream`** processing, that is the *outer* stream. But in the second version the flattened stream consist of the elements of the **sub-lists** which allows splitting the operations in the middle of sub-lists, if feasible. This is impossible in the first version.  As said, this is only relevant if the stream consist of a few rather big sub-lists (and if they vary in size). Since you don’t have intermediate operations between `flatMap` and `collect`, only the `collect` itself is affected so the difference might be very small.

Comment: Alright, if there were operations necessary between `flatMap` and `collect` one should definitely not use the first version. I didn't consider those. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4):

I think the intent of option two is much clearer than that of option one. It took me a few seconds to work out what was happening with the first one, it doesn't look "right" - although it seems valid. Option two was more obvious to me.

Essentially, the intent of what you are doing is a flatmap. If that's the case I'd expect to see flatmap used rather than using addAll().